# Complexity of enumerating over promise problems and circuits?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, quantum-computing, promise-problems, enumeration

Given an enumeration over all Turing Machine which run with increasing length, is there a ``complexity class'' which describes the complexity of determining whether a given TM satisfies the promise for MA (or QMA for a quantum computer). That is, it outputs 1 if the TM we have selected decides correct with probability p>2/3, and outputs 0 otherwise. Presumably such a task is at least (Q)MA-hard?

If, for whatever reason it is not possible to do this for TMs, can we ask the same questions about an enumeration of circuits with increasing depth/gate number?

Comment: The title of the question and the question seem to be different. I'm not sure I got your question, but if I did, then the same proof should work as for RP.

Comment: Is the complexity of determining whether a given TM is in RP known?

Comment: Yes; it is quite easy to show that it's undecidable.

Comment: Surely you could just run the problem multiple times, estimate the acceptance probability, and find the answer? Am I missing something? Or are you assuming that we aren't able to do this (I'm interested in both cases). I suppose otherwise we can apply Rice's theorem?

Comment: The problem is (sticking to RP, for simplicity) that your estimate what you get after many runs might be very close to 1/2. You cannot tell if it's above or below. And as you right the statement does follow from Rice, as there is no 'otherwise' - Rice holds also if you are allowed to run the code.

Comment: @domotorp surely if I have a TM that is guaranteed to run for time $poly(n)$, then the output probabilities are discretised in steps of $2^{poly(n)}$. Thus I can use a TM that runs for exponentially longer to run the same problem, but then amplify with exponentially more time to determine which size of 1/2 the original TM output was?

Comment: Yes, what you write is a method for any $x$ of size $n$ to check if the TM works properly. The problem is checking whether it works properly for every $x$ for every $n$.